# Which type to use in implementation when using function overloading? (and no implicit any)

Tags: typescript

Bare in mind `noImplicitAny` is on.

There is this simple example of overloading a function:

```
interface FUNC {
    (x: number, f: (y: number) => number): number;
    (x: string, f: (y: string) => string ): string;
}

const func: FUNC = function(x, func) {
    return func(x);
}

const result = func('dfd', x => x + '3');
```

You will get that `x` and `func` implicitly have an any type. (use [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20FUNC%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(x%3A%20number%2C%20f%3A%20(y%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(x%3A%20string%2C%20f%3A%20(y%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%20)%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20func%3A%20FUNC%20%3D%20function(x%2C%20func)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20func(x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20func('dfd'%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%20'3')%3B) and turn on "noImplicitAny" to see it)

Which type would you give `x` and `func`? (Right now I'm giving them explicit any, I assume there's a nicer solution, maybe I'm wrong)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
const func: FUNC = function<T>(x: T, func: (x: T) => T) {
    return func(x);
}
```

Comment: That's the right answer. Unfortunately I didn't describe the complexity of my problem well enough. I'll create a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `func` accepts only number and strings, you should give it an union type:

`x: number | string`

Answer (score 0):

If your overloads only differ based on the type, then you can modify your interface to have a generic type parameter:

```
interface FUNC<T> {
    (x: T, f: (y: T) => T): T;
}
```

And use it like:

```
// Parameter types will be inferred based on type parameter.
const numberFunc: FUNC<number> = function(x, func) {
    return func(x);
}

const stringFunc: FUNC<string> = function(x, func) {
    return func(x);
}
const numberResult = numberFunc(1, x => x + 1); // Can't pass strings here
const stringResult = stringFunc("1", x => x + "1"); // Can't pass numbers here
```